# Django URL regex complication

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I am having trouble defining the URLs for my django app.

I want it so that when I type,

http://example.com/post/3        :: I can read a post

http://example.com/post/3/edit   :: I can edit a post

At the moment, I defined it like the following:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$',
    'board.views.edit_post',
    name='edit_post'),

url(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)',
    'board.views.view_post',
    name='view_post'),
```

However this does not seem to work because when I click on my "edit" link which links to

"/post/{{ post.id }}/edit"

I get the intended url in my address bar but am not taken to the edit view...

===================================

--EDIT--

```
@login_required
def edit_post(request, id):
    if id:
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
        if post.owner_user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
#     else:
#         post = Post(owner_user=request.user)

    if request.POST:
        form = PostEditForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() 

            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = PostEditForm()

    return (request,'edit_post.html', {
        'form': form})
```

And

```
def view_post(request, id):   
    #context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.owner = request.user
            form.parent_post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
            form.comment_type = 0
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    return render(request,'view_post.html', {
        #'comment' : get_object_or_404(Comment, parent_post = id),
        'comment': Comment.objects.filter(parent_post=id),
        'form': form,
        'post': get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    })
```

Comment: Sure you've named the view functions correctly? Those routes look OK.

Comment: What happens when you try it with the "/" in the end? For example: "/post/{{ post.id }}/edit/"

Comment: hmm that's strange.. in that case, let me add my view_post and edit_post views

Comment: @GustavoMeira I get : AttributeError at /post/5/edit/    and   'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Because you've missed off the call to `render` at the end of `edit_post`: you're just returning the params directly.

Comment: @GustavoMeira Thank you for the question :) I searched the error and turns out I was an idiot and forgot to put render in my return statement :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll recommend you begin using Class Based Views, besides, why not. Can make your life easier, most times, whiles you write less

```
class UpdatePost(UpdateView):
    model = Post # assuming you've made from your_app.models import Post call already
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'pub_date'] # for demonstration purposes
    template_name = 'post_form.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required) #Use login required on your dispatch method
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pulled = Post.objects.get(id=kwargs['id']) 
        if pulled.created_by == request.user: #just to verify person making edit is rightly disposed to do so
            return super(UpdatePost, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        raise PermissionDenied
```

Sweetly intercept the id in your url like so

```
url(r'^app/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.UpdatePost.as_view(), name='edit'),
```

That's how I do mine. I pulled this from my working project [github.com/seanmavley/menpha.git](http://github.com/seanmavley/menpha.git), but haven't tested this tweaked version. But It should work.